Why is intersphinx able to link to some items in an external project, but not others, in this example?
(Here's the GitHub repo for this example. It includes instructions on running the example and optional scripts to help automate building the documentation.)
Problem
I am using Sphinx + autodoc + autosummary + intersphinx to generate some documentation for a Python project.
I am using intersphinx to link to documentation in external documentation (Polars docs and Python docs), and I find that:

links aren't created to the documentation for Polars DataFrame
but surprisingly links are created however to the documentation for Polars DataType

Python Code
Here's the Python code that I have documented using Sphinx + ReST.
"""Does ``intersphinx`` do its thing?"""

from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Any

import polars as pl

type Hello = str

def make_df(
    greeting: Hello, some_datatype: pl.DataType, some_stuff: Any
) -> pl.DataFrame:
    print(greeting)
    return pl.DataFrame()

My index.rst looks like, based on this SO answer:
myproject documentation
=======================

This is a test to see if intersphinx works as we expect.

.. autosummary::
  :toctree: _autosummary
  :recursive:

  myproject

My conf.py looks like:
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.
#
# For the full list of built-in configuration values, see the documentation:
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html

# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#project-information

project = "myproject"

# -- Project setup -----------------------------------------------------
#

exclude_patterns = [
    "_build",
    "Thumbs.db",
    ".DS_Store",
    ".venv",
    ".vscode",
    "analysis_*",
    "dist",
    "excel",
    "myproject-notebooks",
    "*.md",
    "*.sh",
    "*.toml",
    "./**/__pycache__",
    "*.pyc",
    "docs",
]


def get_main_folder(assumed_folder_name: str) -> Path:
    """Get the full path of the main folder, given its assumed name."""
    cwd = Path(os.getcwd()).absolute()
    # Traverse up from the given path to the root
    for parent in cwd.parents:
        if parent.name == assumed_folder_name:
            return parent

    if cwd.name == assumed_folder_name:
        return cwd

    raise ValueError(
        f"Current working directory does not contain {assumed_folder_name} as a parent!"
    )


myproject_path = get_main_folder("sphinx-doc-test").joinpath("myproject")
print(f"{myproject_path=}")

source_folders = [myproject_path]
print(f"using source folders: {source_folders}")

for folder in source_folders:
    sys.path.insert(0, folder)


# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#general-configuration

extensions = [
    "sphinx.ext.autodoc",
    "sphinx.ext.autosummary",
    "sphinx.ext.intersphinx",
]

templates_path = ["_templates"]

autosummary_generate = True  # Turn on autosummary

autodoc_default_options = {
    "members": True,  # Include members in the documentation
    "undoc-members": True,  # Include undocumented members
    "private-members": False,  # Include private members (starting with _)
    "show-inheritance": True,  # Show base classes
}
autodoc_typehints = "both"

# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/intersphinx.html#configuration

intersphinx_mapping = {
    "python": ("https://docs.python.org/3", None),
    "polars": ("https://docs.pola.rs/api/python/stable", None),
}

# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/todo.html#configuration

todo_include_todos = True


# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#options-for-html-output

html_theme = "alabaster"
html_static_path = ["_static"]

I am using:
dependencies = [
    "polars>=1.6.0",
    "sphinx>=8.0.2",
]
requires-python = ">= 3.12"


Where is your reST markup that contains the references to the external documentation site? Include an example of each that works and does not work. For reference, you can query the object inventory of a site that supports intersphinx with python -m sphinx.ext.intersphinx https://docs.pola.rs/api/python/stable/objects.inv. See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/intersphinx.html#showing-all-links-of-an-intersphinx-mapping-file
